log4j Appender Issue
I have a polling application (using Quartz on a 2-minute cycle) where there are multiple client processes that have their own appenders. I append each process log to its own set of logging files, and that part works fine. The problem is that log4j is throwing an "error ERROR attempted to append to closed appender named SCHEDULE_CON".
SCHEDULE_CON is my console. Here's a snipped of my properties (wouldn't paste correctly in code mode):
# Define the root logger with appender file
log4j.rootLogger = INFO, FILE

log4j2.formatMsgNoLookups
log4j2.appender.console.direct = true

# Direct log messages to SCHEDULE_CON
log4j.appender.SCHEDULE_CON=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.SCHEDULE_CON.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.SCHEDULE_CON.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.SCHEDULE_CON.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# TOA Appt Appender
log4j.appender.toaApptSchedule=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.toaApptSchedule.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.toaApptSchedule.File=log/schedule_poller/toa/toa_appt_schedule_poller.log
log4j.appender.toaApptSchedule.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.toaApptSchedule.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %C{1}:%L - %m%n
log4j.category.toaApptSchedule=INFO, SCHEDULE_CON, toaApptSchedule
log4j.additivity.toaApptSchedule=false

# TOB Appt Appender
log4j.appender.tobApptSchedule=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.tobApptSchedule.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.tobApptSchedule.File=log/schedule_poller/tob/tob_appt_schedule_poller.log
log4j.appender.tobApptSchedule.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.tobApptSchedule.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %C{1}:%L - %m%n
log4j.category.tobApptSchedule=INFO, SCHEDULE_CON, tobApptSchedule
log4j.additivity.tobApptSchedule=false

I tried it with SCHEDULE_CON in the set in the rootLogger and that didn't seem to help. It sometimes works OK when there are only 2 processes cycling. Once I bump it up to 10-15, the closed appender errors show.
So, I basically want each appender to log to its file, but also dump to the console.
Thanks - David
